# Mac Users - Bootcamp, VirtualBox, or something else to use Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, boot-camp, visual-studio-2010

I'm taking a computer science class that requires students to use Visual Studio and SQL Management Studio for programming assignments. I have been using Macbook Pro, so i'm considering getting either Bootcamp or VirtualBox since they are free. Can anyone recommend me which one to use or have any suggestions for something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for maximum performance would be to install Windows using BootCampand then install and use your software there. VirtualBox should also work, but there might be some performance compromises. 
The call is completely yours. If you dont want to reboot your Mac to log in to BootCamp, then VirtualBox is the way to go. But if you are ok rebooting to BootCamp, I'd recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been running VirtualPC and VirtualBox on Windows and found VB to be more versatile and able to import other vm's easily.  I have had issues trying to export vm's to share on different machines using VB but no less than the new VirtualPC on Win7.

Im now using VB on OSX.  Couldn't get bootcamp to work kept getting "missing drivers error" when trying to install W7P.  Same ISO worked flawlessly and faster installing on VB.

So far no problems using networking, USB and serial ports on VB.  Make sure your MBP has lots of RAM and HD.